# Deciding whether to use a one-to-many, many-to-many, or one-to-one relationship with Parse.com for iOS photo sharing app

Tags: ios, many-to-many, parse-platform, one-to-many, one-to-one

I am creating a photo sharing app for the iPhone using Parse.com and so far everything has been pretty easy and I just finished writing the code for uploading photos to the Parse server.

So far, I have been using the default "_User" class. Here are some of the key types of data that are being stored for each user: objectId, username, email, and an array object called "friends" that contains the usernames of other users in the database that the user has added to their friends list.

Now, I need to setup the actual sharing functionality between users. I have been going through the Parse documentation and I need to decide whether to use a one-to-many, many-to-many, or one-to-one relationship. Depending on which one I end up choosing, I then will need to decide between using pointers, arrays, parse relations, or join tables.

I am going to quickly explain the "sharing" functionality that I am trying to achieve:

1. For my photo app, user1 starts the "relationship" by taking a photo and choosing to send it to a friend on their friends list named user2 .
2. The photo is then uploaded to Parse and sent to user2.
3. user2 receives the photo from user1.
4. user2 opens the photo and it is their job to "finish" the "relationship" by using the app's editing tools and drawing something random on the original photo. Example: user2 draws a heart next to user1's face in the photo.
5. When user2 is finished, the final photo is saved to their profile and also sent back to the original sender, user1, and the "relationship" is now finished and completed/closed.

After reading through the docs and doing my own research, I have come to the conclusion that I need to use a Many-To-Many relationship using Join Tables so that I can include metadata.

However, I am new to objective-c and programming in general and it would be lazy of me if I did not ask for input and advice before getting started when it is possible that I have chosen the wrong solution or an unnecessary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more about your DB management than anything to do with Obj-C.

Think about using a new class in your DB called `SharedImage` which hosts the image(s), a link to the originator and the recipient (1 to 1, so could us a pointer or a relationship) and any other data you need.

Now you can create these objects are you require and you can fetch them based on queries using the current user.

Also, for your existing `friends` array which you said holds the usernames of the friends - it would probably be better to store the `objectId`s of the friends instead of the usernames (because the username can usually be changed, but the objectId is static).

Comment: thanks for the reply. You know what, I would love to store the objectId's of the friends instead of the usernames, and I'd like to do this with Pointers but I just can't figure it out. I can successfully create Pointers by grabbing the current user, but can only get objectId's to store as strings of text.

Comment: Array of objectid as strings should be ok for querying. You can use an array of pointers though: https://www.parse.com/questions/array-of-pointer

Comment: here is what confuses me about this. If a user logs in, and I grab their objectId, and then I want to find all of the photos that are connected to their objectId, then that means I'll have to scan through every single "photo" entry in Parse to see if their objectId is attached to it. If I have millions of photo entries in my server, then won't that take forever?

Comment: In the original sample code from parse they used pointers for that, but the current guidance is to use relationships. You'd need to ask them about scaling and expected performance though...

Comment: in general though, once you have millions of entries in a database, pointers to objectId's would be better for performance than arrays correct? Because wouldn't it be like this? User logs in and you just pull all data "pointing" to current user's objectId vs. user logs in and scan every single entry in DB to see if the array contains objectId.

Comment: I'd say it's probably as scan anyway as parse (IIRC) stores everything as JSON. But relationships are better than arrays, particularly or strings, and particularly of usernames

Comment: In regards to the above comment, by using pointers, it would be precise, but if you were using arrays you would have to scan through every single entry in the DB to see if any of their arrays contain the objectId. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused with your comment "relationships are better than arrays" because in the Parse docs these are all "relationships" and then you have to choose whether arrays, pointers, Parse Relations, or Join Tables.

Comment: You'd need to ask parse about the implementation details of array or pointers / relationships. This kind of thing is why indexes exist in databases

Comment: I meant `Parse Relations`. For queries about the best option to go for with specific future requirements in mind you should use the parse forum

Comment: thank you so much. So just to be clear your final comment was "But Parse Relations are better than arrays, particularly for* strings, and particularly for* usernames."

Comment: yes, an array of strings will be worst, array of pointers *should* be better, Parse Relations should be better again, not sure where join tables fits in...

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I am going to play around more then with Parse Relations. I think I'm going to take some time and learn about databases in general too. Before I go search for some videos, would you mind quickly explaining what you meant by "This kind of thing is why indexes exist in databases" - do indexes exist to make complicated "searches" in a DB like this faster?

Comment: thank you. Users like you are what make stack overflow great for complete noobs like me. Hopefully one day I'll be able to answer these questions for someone else. cheers.